# How to change a value inside an object in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'tasks' and each document have an object array called 'resolver' with 14 elements so the structure looks like this:

```
tasks
  --resolver
    --1: false
    --2: false
    .
    .
    .
    --14: false
```

How can I change any of the items inside to true?

I tried this:

```
  updateElement(task: Task) {
    var ref = this.afs.doc(`tasks/${task.id}`).collection('resolver').doc('7'); <--Element 7 (?
    return ref.update(true) <-- Set to true (?
  }
```

Comment: Is 7 a string or a number? In your ref, it's a string. Do you get any errors? What happens instead of the expected action?

Comment: 7 is a number inside 'resolver' object but my approach doesnt work either with 7 or '7'

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access fields inside a Firestore document, the same way as you can in the RTDB.  You need to get the document, edit the `resolver` object and write it back to the original document.  If you want to ensure that no other code modifies at the same time, wrap it in a transaction.

Here's an example, using the Node SDK. You can modify it to suit your environment.

```
updateElement(task) {
  let taskRef = firestore.doc(`tasks/${task.id}`);
  return firestore.runTransaction(taskTransaction => {
    return taskTransaction.get(taskRef)
      .then(taskDoc => {
        let resolver = taskDoc.data().resolver;
        resolver.7 = true;
        taskTransaction.update(taskRef, resolver)
      })
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
  });
}
```